# Select file location from file explorer in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've got a very simple batch file that uses the following code to take all files with a certain extension in a specified location and creates a text file with the name of all of them listed.

```
    c:\
    cd C:\Users\Person\Desktop\folder
    dir /b *.csv>list2.lst
```

Just wondering if instead of having to edit my text file and copy/paste the file location I can have it open file explorer so I can select the file and have that location saved as a text variable.

Comment: Yes you can, but as batch files are CLI, not GUI, you'll need to leverage another scripting language from within your batch file.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option.

Create a batch-file containing:

```
pushd "%~1" || exit /b 1
if exist *.csv dir /b *.csv > list2.lst
```

Add this batch-file into your user profile directory i.e. in directory of `C:\Users\James`.

Hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> key, select the desired folder in explorer to process, right click to select `Send to` in the context menu  and then select the batch-file in the `Send to` menu to run it.

If all went well, you will have `list2.lst` in the directory of the desired folder if .csv files exist in that directory.

The <kbd>shift</kbd> key held down is needed to see the extended context menu.

When you say text variable, `%~1` in the code contains the path to the folder, which I expect applies to the text variable as you mention.